# Scrape web page with splashr and load more button

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm try to scrape a few [1801 census pages](https://digitalarkivet.no/en/census/district/tf01058443000001) with `splashr` that may have 0 to many Load More buttons (since 50 records are loaded at a time).  This page should have 174.

```
url <- "https://digitalarkivet.no/en/census/district/tf01058443000001"
doc <-  splash("localhost") %>% render_html(url, wait =3)
html_nodes(doc2, xpath="//h4[not(@class)]/a") %>% length()
[1] 50
```

I tried following the url by Load More, but that just gets the first 50 records again.

```
url2 <- html_nodes(doc, xpath="//div[@class='load-more']") %>% html_attr("data-url")
[1] "https://digitalarkivet.no/en/census/related/rural-residences/tf01058443000001?page=2"
```

Note that most districts have fewer than 50 records, so I don't need to click load more for every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx for trying the `splashr` package (I'm the author).

Thankfully, you won't need it in this case. The data load is done through XHR requests which we can mimic in R:

```
library(httr)
library(rvest)

census_page <- function(district, page=1L) {

  GET(
    url = "https://digitalarkivet.no",
    path=sprintf("en/census/related/rural-residences/%s", district),
    accept_json(),
    add_headers(
      `User-Agent` = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.45 Safari/537.36", 
      Referer = "https://digitalarkivet.no/en/census/district/tf01058443000001", 
      `X-Requested-With` = "XMLHttpRequest"
    ),
    query = list(page=page)
  ) -> res

  stop_for_status(res)

  res <- content(res)

  list(
    divs = read_html(res$view),
    next_page = parse_url(res$nextPage)$query$page
  )

}
```

Now, just pass-in the district and page of data you want:

```
res <- census_page("tf01058443000001", 1)
```

And get the results:

```
str(res, 1)
## List of 2
##  $ divs     :List of 2
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "xml_document" "xml_node"
##  $ next_page: chr "2"
```

The function returns a `list` with:

- `divs` which is the parsed content containing the `<div>`s of the info you want
- `next_page` can be used to pass to another call of the function

I didn't try it through to the end (i.e. I don't know if there will always be a 'next page') and you will need to extract the data from the `<div>`s on your own, but this will help you avoid a third-party dependency.